# Taking Facebook values (email, name, etc) from one view controller and transferring them to another one

Tags: swift, xcode, facebook, swift3, facebook-php-sdk

So I'm currently designing an application and am working on the account registration. I've implemented Facebook login into it but I am having trouble taking a user's Facebook information and transferring it to the next page, where, ideally, the fields for name and email would be filled with those values received from Facebook.

The initial page with the Facebook login looks like this:

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.frame = CGRect(x: 82, y: 325, width: view.frame.width - 210, height: 59)

    loginButton.delegate = self
}

func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!) {
    print("Did log out of facebook")
}

func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {
    if error != nil {
        print(error)
        return
    }
    print("Successfully logged in")

    FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"]).start {(connection, result, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("Failed to start graph request", err)
            return
        } else {

            guard let data = result as? [String:Any] else {return}

            let fbEmail = data["email"]
            let fbName  = data["name"]
        }

        print(result)
    }

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    //get destination view an set the fullname

        let vc = segue.destination as? CreateAccountVC
        vc?.email = self.fbEmail
        vc.fullname = self.fbName

}
override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

And the next view controller, a typical registration page, has these text fields:

```
@IBOutlet weak var fullname: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var username: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var age: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var email: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var verifyEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var password: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var verifyPassword: UITextField!
```

I have no idea how to take the values from Facebook and put them into these text entry boxes. I'm very new to programming so any help would be much appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First, store the FB values in a var(s) you can access later.

Next, You can set the values for your next view before you transition. For example if you are using a segue, you can do it in the prepareForSegue like this:

```
class RegisterVC: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

var fbName:String?

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
  //get destination view an set the fullname
  let vc=segue.destination as? MyCustomVC
  vc.fullName=self.fbName 
}
```

Comment: This may sound dumb, but would this be in the RegisterVC (first piece of code above) or the VC containing my text entry boxes?

Comment: It would go in the first view.

Comment: I used this code and it is giving me the error "value of type UIViewController has no member "email".  I set my variables like this:                                   let fbEmail : NSString? = data["email"]! as? NSString

Comment: You need to cast it as your custom view controller class so it will know about the bars you created

Comment: Dude, I really appreciate the help, you're the man. I'm still getting an error, I declared the Facebook values within the loginButton function like this "let fbEmail = data["email"]", however, when I run the code, I get an error saying that "Value of type RegisterVC has no member fbEmail. I'm gonna update my code up top, sorry, I'm new to stack overflow haha

Comment: you need to declare bfEmail outside of the loginButton so it is available to the entire class. Add it to your class like above (I editied the code)

Comment: I got some fatal error, I'll figure this out. Thanks for all your help though. Very cool of you